# Sistema de Templates django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Buenos días ante todos mis saludos y agradecimientos por su colaboración. Tengo la siguiente duda, como puedo crear una variable acumulativa en un template de django.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres por variable acumulativa? Django (o mejor, jinja2) tiene capacidades de cálculo muy limitadas. Mejor hacías ese cálculo en la vista y le pasabas al template el resultado.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias de todas formas necesitaba hacerlo desde la plantilla pero con otras respuestas del blog he resuelto muchas gracias.